# Iptables: what does this command do?

Tags: linux, iptables

```
iptables -I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name DEFAULT --rsource
```

I understand the first half of the command but have no idea what the second half (after -m state) does. I have read a couple of resources online and looked at 'man iptables' and although I have an idea of what each individual switch does, I don't know how to make sense of it together.

Comment: Does the answer work good for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule will add the source `ip` address to `ipset` called `DEFAULT` for every new connection that calling `port 22` which coming from `eth1` using `tcp` protocol

- Using the `-m` switch to load a module
- The `state` module is able to examine the state of a packet and
  determine if it is `NEW`, `ESTABLISHED` or `RELATED`. `NEW` refers to
  incoming packets that are new incoming connections that weren't
  initiated by the host system.
- The `recent` module takes a number of options:

  1. `--name` xyz give a name to the particular ‘class’ you are defining
  2. `--rsource` in the list you keep, use the remote (source) address

Comment: @anna Does the answer work good with you ?